# Naked Python-JS script

Tags: javascript, python, naked-objects

When using the Naked library of python to launch jv scripts with parameters it gives me the same problem all the time, of a parameter not defined.
This is the python code:

```
from Naked.toolshed.shell import execute_js, muterun_js
pi=str(8)
response = execute_js('file.js', pi)
```

And here the file.js code:

```
console.log(pi);
```

As you see it´s a very simple code because but I can´t figure out how to send a parameter without declaring it.
I saw a similar question like this but the main problem here is that I don´t know how to declare in the javascript code a variable that it comes from "out"

Comment: You’re only passing the value `'8'`, there’s no way for JS to understand there’s a variable called “pi”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`Naked`](https://naked.readthedocs.io/toolshed_shell.html) docs:

> The execute_js() function runs the execute() function on a Node.js script file. Instead of passing the command to be executed as the first parameter, pass a Node.js script filepath as the first parameter and any additional command arguments as the second parameter (optional)

So the problem is not in python but in the `Node.js` program.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-write-and-run-your-first-program-in-node-js) you can find a description on how to pass arguments to a node program when running from console.

I think the solution to your problem is to change the node program as follows:

```
var pi = process.argv[2];
console.log(pi);
```

Where you pick the third argument since the first two are respectively the node.js path and the current program path.

UPDATE: if you want to pass more than 1 variable, you simply have to pass all the variables as a blank separated string as the second argument of `execute_js`.

Example:

Python side

```
pi = 8
rho = 10

arg_in = f"{pi} {rho}" # for older versions of python you can use "{pi} {rho}".format(pi=pi, rho=rho)

response = execute_js('file.js', arg_in)
```

Js side

```
var pi = process.argv[2],
    rho = process.argv[3];

console.log(pi, rho)
```

You can pass as many arguments as you want, adapting this with lists and for cycles, you can pass a dynamic number of arguments.

Comment: It worked great, but how could I do it for two variables?

Comment: Thanks a Lot!
Just one last question, when using the parameter I use a link, and print it on pyton and then with js, but it seems js cut it when a & appears in the link, is there a way to tell js not to cut the code when finding a & ?

Comment: Sorry to ask you again but when using 2 parameters if one is a phrase like "This is a example" why Js only recibes the first word?